# How to fix "detected conflict" error when installing Rust on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, rust, installation, rustup

I am trying to install Rust which is failing with following error:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc'
info: latest update on 2019-02-28, rust version 1.33.0 (2aa4c46cf 2019-02-28)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: installing component 'rustc'
57.7 MiB /  57.7 MiB (100 %)   2.6 MiB/s ETA:   0 s
info: installing component 'rust-std'
51.4 MiB /  51.4 MiB (100 %)   4.9 MiB/s ETA:   0 s
info: installing component 'cargo'
  2.8 MiB /   2.8 MiB (100 %) 152.0 KiB/s ETA:   0 s
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
  8.5 MiB /   8.5 MiB (100 %) 281.6 KiB/s ETA:   0 s
info: rolling back changes
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\8va7fsfks8zkeb5b_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\share/man'
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\mybj8dkhr27yqlzf_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\share/man/man1'
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\5l3hc8i6tp_6rqsa_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin'
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\ejk4eeibyz0dkgjt_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/etc'
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\1758r_0hyzkhtohi_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/bin'
error: could not rename component file from 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\tmp\5_0tdsg3gat5u6yy_dir\bk' to 'C:\Users\rraut\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/codegen-backends'
error: failed to install component: 'rust-docs-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc', detected conflict: '"share/doc/rust/html"'
```

Any one has faced same issue before on Windows 10?

Comment: You may find an answer in the [user forum](https://users.rust-lang.org). I remember reading a similar question once.

Comment: There's [similar issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/1436#issuecomment-430436195) with some tips. Not sure if it will solve your problem, but worth to try it.

Comment: @zrzka Unfortunately I don’t have access to those settings, need to go to infra team to change those settings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was running into the same issue.  The way I solved it was by manually reinstalling the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain which apparently got corrupted while installing.

I did:

```
rustup toolchain remove stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Then:

```
rustup install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

**Some notes**:

- You can get the toolchain name (they're divided by their release channel: stable, nightly, beta) by navigating to your user folder and finding the `.rustup` folder (E.g: `C:Users\MyWindowsUser\.rustup\toolchains`)
- This should also fix the RLS extension for VSCode.

Comment: Thanks Man! It worked for me. The only problem is I have to manually set the environment variable to run rustc.